# Using "ifempty" and "notempty" in Modx Revolution

Tags: html, css, modx, modx-revolution

I'm trying to use "ifempty" and "notempty" for a banner-style image that's created with a TV (*pageBanner). When no image is added, I need a 52px spacer added for the rest of the page content. Here's what I have so far:

```
[[*pageBanner:notempty=`[[$pageImage]]`]]
[[*pageBanner:ifempty=`<div id="no-image-spacer"></div>`]]

<div id="content-wrapper">

    [[Breadcrumb? &exclude=`2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15`]]
    [[$pageBody]]

</div>
```

CSS for #no-image-spacer:

```
#no-image-spacer {
    padding-top: 52px;
}
```

And chunk pageImage:

```
<img src="[[*pageBanner]]" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="display: block; max-height: 270px; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; padding-top: 52px;" />
```

It's working when there is no image in the TV (creating the spacer div), but when there is an image inserted in the TV, it displays the image and adds the file name below the image (but doesn't create the spacer div). Any idea why it's adding the file name? Seems really bizarre but I'm probably missing something terribly obvious.

Oh and the website is at http://104.193.173.104/modx/index.php if you want to check out the output of chrome inspector. In the left navigation, Maps has an image and the rest don't.

Cheers!

Comment: Is that all the code in your page?

Comment: @haakon319 Ignore that last comment, original post has been updated with the whole page in question. Thanks!

Comment: For the filename, check image TV's output options, if it is other than "default".

Comment: Somewhere `[[*pageBanner]]` which you didn't copy? Tried displaying the pageBanner itself to test what ouput you'll get? Tried using the `:toPlaceholder`? Does replacing `:ifempty` with a `:else` statement help?

Comment: @ZaighamR Thanks for that idea! It was set to "default" but I'm experimenting with changing it to "Image", calling `[[*pageBanner]]` from the original "notempty" statement, and putting all those properties from pageImage into the TV. Might simplify things a bit and clear up a mistake. I'll keep this posted.

It worked! I'll post an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ZaighamR I have come up with a solution!

The chunk pageContent now reads:

```
[[*pageBanner:notempty=``]]
[[*pageBanner:ifempty=`<div id="no-image-spacer"></div>`]]
```

... which calls the pageBanner TV itself (instead of my old system of calling the pageImage chunk to call the TV). Then I changed the output of the TV from "default" to "Image" and added all the properties from my pageImage chunk to their respective fields:

```
<img src="[[*pageBanner]]" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="display: block; max-height: 270px; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; padding-top: 52px;" />
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can string together output modifiers too so you could have:

```
[[*pageBanner:notempty=`
    <img src="[[*pageBanner]]" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="display: block; max-height: 270px; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; padding-top: 52px;" />
`:default=`
    <div id="no-image-spacer"></div>`
]]
```